# HTML - How to do a Confirmation popup to a Submit button and then send the request?

Tags: html, django, submit

I am learning web development using `Django` and have some problems in where to put the code taking chage of whether to submit the request in the `HTML code`.

Eg. There is webpage containing a `form`(a blog) to be filled by the user, and upon click on the Save button,there is a pop up asking whether you want to `confirm` or not. If click on `confirm`, then the request is sent.

I searched and find this `javascript` code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function clicked() {
    alert('clicked');
}
```

```
<input type="submit" onclick="clicked();" value="Button" />
```

But I guess this is not the correct function as it seems to me that whenever you click on the Button, the request will be submitted. So How can I delay the submit request until user has confirm the submit?

Comment: The correct answer is by @Isaac

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I believe you want to use confirm()

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clicked() {
       if (confirm('Do you want to submit?')) {
           yourformelement.submit();
       } else {
           return false;
       }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 223):

The most compact version:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" />
```

The key thing to note is the `return`

-

Because there are many ways to skin a cat, here is another alternate method:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="submit" onclick="clicked(event)" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
function clicked(e)
{
    if(!confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Perfect answer !

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: it works but can I change OK and CANCEL buttons with YES and NO ?

Comment: @Web.11 unfortunately no, as this is built into the browser

Answer (score 7):

Use [`window.confirm()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.confirm) instead of [`window.alert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.alert).

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return clicked();" value="Button" />
```

JavaScript:

```
function clicked() {
    return confirm('clicked');
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more on what will this function affect,ie. Form my understanding, previously without this function,the form POST request will be send whenever we click on the submit button. Now I want to make the user confirm their submit before they the POST request is send. So the solution above will delay the sending of request after we click on OK of the confirm() pop up?

Comment: That is correct. The JavaScript waits until the `confirm()` has finished executing before continuing on, and the `return` either halts or permits the event.

Comment: Instead of onclick, it should be onsubmit. 
Else even if you hit 'Cancel' the form submission will go through.

Answer (score 6):

For a Django form, you can add the confirmation dialog inside the form tag:

```
<form action="{% url 'delete' %}" method="POST" onsubmit="return confirm ('Are you sure?')">
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

function foo() {


var user_choice = window.confirm('Would you like to continue?');


if(user_choice==true) {


window.location='your url';  // you can also use element.submit() if your input type='submit' 


} else {


return false;


}
}

</script>

<input type="button" onClick="foo()" value="save">
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option that you can use is:

```
onclick="if(confirm('Do you have sure ?')){}else{return false;};"
```

using this function on submit button you will get what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onclick` in the submit button:

```html
<button type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"/>Delete</button>
```

You can also use `onsubmit` in the form:

```html
<form action="/" method="POST" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure?');">
  <button type="submit"/>Delete</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the onClick function to the button

```
 <input type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).