# Open pop-up box on button click if an option is selected

Tags: html, button, popup, radio-button

### Explanation

I am making a website, mostly based on `html` and have a form with three radio buttons and a `Submit Button`. I want that if the user clicks on the Submit button, a `pop-up box` should say that the opinion was submitted. I am new to html and didn't find a suitable answer. `JavaScript` or `CSS` would work.

### Example Code

```
<form action="">
<b> What do you think is powerful on the other? </b> <br> 
<input type="radio" name="abc" value="1">Pros<br>
<input type="radio" name="abc" value="2">Cons <br>
<input type="radio" name="abc" value="3">Both are equal <br>
<input type = "Submit" value ="Submit">
</form>
```

The designing, placement and appearance of this part is fine. I just need to know how to show a `pop-up box` on button click which should say, "Your opinion was submitted!". I don't care if the user selected Option 1, 2 or 3. It is just a formality.

**EDIT**

But if the user doesn't select any, then it would be a trouble. How to know if the user didn't select any option. In this case, the pop-up box should say, "Select an option!"

What would be the way to achieve this, if any?

Comment: This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849117/html-how-to-do-a-confirmation-popup-to-a-submit-button-and-then-send-the-reque adresses the exact same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
<form action="">
 <b> What do you think is powerful on the other? </b> <br> 
 <input type="radio" name="abc" value="1">Pros<br>
  <input type="radio" name="abc" value="2">Cons <br>
  <input type="radio" name="abc" value="3">Both are equal <br>
  <input type="submit" onclick="return alert('Your opinion was submitted')" />
</form>
```

Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t56GZ/4/

Or here is another option: http://jsfiddle.net/DBHEz/208/

```
<form action="www.google.com"onSubmit="if(!alert('Your opinion was submitted')){return false;}">
  <b> What do you think is powerful on the other? </b> <br> 
  <input type="radio" name="abc" value="1">Pros<br>
  <input type="radio" name="abc" value="2">Cons <br>
  <input type="radio" name="abc" value="3">Both are equal <br>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you please answer the Edit I made in my question?

Comment: @KashishArora please accept some answer to finish your question.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest option would be to add an `onclick` attribute with `alert('Your opinion was submitted!')` e.g.

```
<form action="">
<b> What do you think is powerful on the other? </b> <br> 
<input type="radio" name="abc" value="1">Pros<br>
<input type="radio" name="abc" value="2">Cons <br>
<input type="radio" name="abc" value="3">Both are equal <br>
<input type="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="alert('Your opinion was submitted!')">
</form>
```

Alternatively you could look into using modals to present the user with a slightly nicer 'pop up'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It surely went my way. I have edited my question. Can you answer that please?