# Django Confirm a form before submitting it

Tags: django, forms, post

I've got a form which I retrieve data for in form.cleaned_data.
I wish to render this data to another page for the submitter to review before it is entered in the DB.
Now, I can just use render(request,"xyz.html","datax":form.cleaned_data}
to render it to the user, but I am stuck at how to re-submit this data as POST from this page.
How should I store this data in the next page so that it can be resent to me with my "confirm" button.

Please do not suggest form preview in django. I do not wish to use that, but write my own.

Comment: just create  in xyz.html  another form and hide {{datax}}

Comment: Hi, yes I can do this. It is very similar to uhsac's approach of re-rendering the form itself.
As for hiding the form, I can do it by extending my form class object and iterating over the fields and setting the widget as "hidden". Is there a better way to do this, like form.hide() or something.? thanks.

Comment: why you don't use another approach Form wizard https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/

Comment: Form Wizard went solo in 1.8 under the name *django-formtools*. https://github.com/django/django-formtools/

Comment: add to the button `onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849117/html-how-to-do-a-confirmation-popup-to-a-submit-button-and-then-send-the-reque

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't send form.cleaned_data but just the form

Per example :

```
# In view1
form = Form(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    return render(request, 'view2.html', form)

# In view2
form = Form(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```

Comment: This will leave the form to be editable again, but still it does solve my problem. I can also hide the form itself, this is also mentioned by slim_ch, your approaches are similar. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably better to submit it straight to the database in the first step, but add a "reviewed" booleanfield which is only set to true after the second step.

Comment: Please elaborate as to why this is a good idea? I mean, if I save it and have a boolean field, won't it be a hassle to check and then remove the data? is it not better to just save it once after confirmation? Thanks.