# Django returning None instead of a HTTP response

Tags: django

OK im probably doing this all wrong!
I am trying to run a function in a view which calls another view. 
This seems to pass my request into the next function as a POST method before loading the form from the second function.

my views.py

```
''' This section of hte code seems to function correctly '''
@login_required()
def joinLeague(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        league = JoinLeagueQueue(user=request.user)

        form = JoinLeagueForm(instance=league, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            context = int(league.id) # displays id of model, JoinLeagueQueue
            return HttpResponseRedirect(confirmLeague(request, context))

    else:
        form = JoinLeagueForm()
        context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'userteams/joinleagueform.html', context)
```

This section of the views file is not working correctly.
it seems to run the POST request without displaying the GET request with the form first.

```
@login_required()
def confirmLeague(request, league):
    # gets ID of application to join league
    joinleagueid=JoinLeagueQueue.objects.get(id=league) 

    pin = joinleagueid.pin # gets pin from application
    user = joinleagueid.user # get user from application
    leagueinquestion=League.objects.get(leaguePin=pin) # gets the league record for applied league
    manager=leagueinquestion.leagueManager # Gets the league manager for league applied for
    leaguename=leagueinquestion.leagueName # Gets the league name for league applied for
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'accept' in request.POST:
            LeaguesJoinedTo.objects.create(
                leaguePin = pin,
                playerjoined = user,
            )
            return redirect('punterDashboard')# user homepage
        else:
            print("Error in POST request")
    else:
        context = {'leaguename':leaguename, 'pin':pin, 'manager':manager}
        return render(request, 'userteams/confirmleague.html', context)
```

I now get an error saying Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/userteams/None
Using the URLconf defined in fanfoo_proj.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

... im skipping a list of the patterns. 
10. userteams/ confirmLeague [name='confirmLeague']

Answer (score 0):

Ok i think the better way would be a HttpRedirect to the second view:

```
return confirmLeague(request, context)
```

should change to something like:

```
return redirect(confirmLeague,args=league)
```

django doc to urlresolvers: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. Still not working however. The problem seems to be that when the function is called
    return confirmLeague(request, context)
It seems to deal with a post request without having first rendered the page: 
return render(request, 'userteams/confirmleague.html', context)

Comment: also another question: towards which view points the form? it should point to the `joinLeague` view not to the other?

can you share your template?

Comment: ok  to clarify you want a view where the user can select and then you want to display the selection where the user confirms?

if yes then the first view should in the post only read the league and pass it to the confirm view and in the confirm view in the post you do the adding

this would mean you still need the redirect  but don't need the `form.save()`

Comment: I am trying to create a form which allows the user to type in a pin. This uses the joinLeague function to run Get/POST. if it is a POST, it will pass the pin onto the next function, confirmLeague. This is so the user can double check they are joining the correct league. 
If they click join, the form should return 'accept' an input and then run the post method and return the user to their homepage, punterDashboard
Here is my files on github [link](https://github.com/learnICT/Djangos/tree/master/example/app)

Comment: ok scratch that i said you don't need the form.save() you do need it since you are storing those before they are definitive that's ok

Comment: you can't call the view function you have to **redirect** to it with the appropriate context:

this means change: `return HttpResponseRedirect(confirmLeague(request, context))`

to `return redirect(confirmLeague,args=league) `

Comment: NoReverseMatch at /userteams/joinLeague
Reverse for 'userteams.views.confirmLeague' with keyword arguments '{'args': <JoinLeagueQueue: JoinLeagueQueue object (37)>}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['userteams/confirmLeague/(?P<league>[^/]+)$']

Comment: as the error says you have to adjust the urls.py that it accepts beeing called with a joinleaguequeue object

Comment: I think the fact that I am doing a query above is affecting the data that I am now passing to confirmLeague() function.

Do you know how I can overcome this?

Comment: as said before check that your view can be called with a **JoinLeagueQueue** or with the ID of such an object (then you have to pass the id instead of the object as a args) and it will work

in your question you send the post request to the other view which is not working because you want to **redirect** to the second view if a post is done on the first one and **get** the second view

Comment: I've edited the above code I had (which is probably not smart because the question is different) .
Is it possible you can take a look at the problem I have now. I've checked as you said and the view seems to be able to called but does not run the get request correctly.

Comment: Although it's not what I want to do, I may change the way the initial form works and create something similar to the solution for confirming a form [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25041417/django-confirm-a-form-before-submitting-it)

Answer (score 0):

```
def joinLeague(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        league = JoinLeagueQueue(user=request.user)

        form = JoinLeagueForm(instance=league, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            context = league.id

            return HttpResponseRedirect( reverse("your_confirmLeague_url",kwargs={'league':context}) )
    else:
        form = JoinLeagueForm()
        context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'userteams/joinleagueform.html', context)


def confirmLeague(request, league):
    league = get_object_or_404(JoinLeagueQueue, pk=league)
    pin = league.pin
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'accept' in request.POST: # This refers to the action from my form which is waiting for a button press in a html form.
            LeaguesJoinedTo.objects.create(
                leaguePin = pin,
                playerjoined = request.user.id,
            )

            return redirect('punterDashboard')

    else:
        context = {'league':league}
        return render(request, 'userteams/confirmleague.html', context)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. unfortunately no luck.
It seems to run the post request in confirmLeague function as opposed to rendering the page on the last line of the code.