# How to style a javascript popup confirmation window on Submit button?

Tags: javascript, php, css

Basically, I've got a image as submit button and when it's clicked, it will appear a popup asking if they are sure about what they are going to submit.
Like here: [HTML - How to do a Confirmation popup to a Submit button and then send the request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849117/html-how-to-do-a-confirmation-popup-to-a-submit-button-and-then-send-the-reque)

So, I am asking are there already any plugins with pre-styled popups or basically how I can style this popup because as default its using the Windows OS style or the browser one ...

Comment: `So, I am asking are there already any plugins with pre-styled popups` there are hundreds, spend 10 minutes on google and you'll be spoilt for choice.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot style `confirm();` alerts. They are generic to the browser. If you want to style alerts then you can try an alternatives such as the [jQuery dialog box](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation).

Here is a good Demo you can have a look at [How to Create a jQuery Confirm Dialog Replacement](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/12/better-confirm-box-jquery-css3/)

Comment: I understand, so can I use this dialog box similiar to the alert to make sure they confirm before submit is posted?

Comment: Yes, you can have a look at this fiddle someone has put together [jQueryUIConfirm](http://jsfiddle.net/taditdash/vvjj8/)