# Delete object with form in django

Tags: django

I'm displaying a table. In every line there should be a delete button which deletes the element from the table.

My problem is, I'm not sure how to pass the id of the element to the view.

html:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <div>
        <h3>Zuletzt ausgewählt:</h3>
        <p>published: <b>{{ post.pub_date }}</b>
        </p>
        <p>
            name: <b>{{ post.Name }}</b>
            anmeldung: <b>{{ post.get_Anmeldung_display }}</b>
            essen: <b>{{ post.get_Essen_display }}</b>
                <form action="" method="POST">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  <input class="btn btn-default btn-danger" name="delete" type="submit" value="Löschen"/>
                </form>
        </p>
        <p>
            Email: <b>{{ post.Email }}</b>
        </p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST' and 'delete' in request.POST:
    Eintrag.objects.filter(pk=id).delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)
```

So I need to pass post.pub_date of every post to the view, how can I accomplish that?

Comment: > So I need to pass post.pub_date of every post to the view, how can I accomplish that?  
No, it's the view that is passing post.pub_date to the templates, why should it pass it back ?

Comment: hm, the button should know which post to delete - your right passing post.pub_date to the button is the real question

Comment: add an attribute: `<input id="{{ post.pk }}" ... />` and an AJAX call to the view passing the pk to delete

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My problem is, I'm not sure how to pass the id of the element to the view.

I can think of two ways to do this. I'll cover them both one by one.

**1.** Create a separate url route in your app specifically for deleting objects:

```
('/post/<pk>/delete/', name="delete_post"),
```

Then point your form's `action` to this url:

```
<form action="{% url 'delete_post' post.pk %}" method="POST">
    ...
```

Finally, modify your view function to accept the `pk` argument:

```
def my_view(request, pk): 
    ...
```

---

**2.** Second method is to just create another field in your form and pass it the pk of the object:

Just create another field in your form.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ post.pk }}" name="pk">
    ...
```

Then in your view just look at `request.POST['pk']` to get the pk of the post.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. I like the second idea but I get a MultiValueDictKeyError with request.POST['pk'], any idea?

Comment: @Sebastian Ah yes. I forgot to add the `name="pk"` attribute to the input field.

Answer (score 3):

A non-ajax way which is super easy to implement as it uses the Django generic views is this:

template.html

```
{% for post in posts %}
<div>
    <h3>Zuletzt ausgewählt:</h3>
    <p>published: <b>{{ post.pub_date }}</b>
    </p>
    <p>
        name: <b>{{ post.Name }}</b>
        anmeldung: <b>{{ post.get_Anmeldung_display }}</b>
        essen: <b>{{ post.get_Essen_display }}</b>
            <form action="" method="POST">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <input class="btn btn-default btn-danger" name="delete" type="submit" value="Löschen"/>
            </form>
    </p>
    <p>
        Email: <b>{{ post.Email }}</b>
    </p>
    <a href="/deleteurl/{{ post.pk }}">
        Delete this!
    </a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Once the user clicks on the delete link they will be redirected to the delete view and template which will have a URL that looks like this "/deleteurl/1/".

Then your set of views, url, and template for processing the delete could look like this:

views.py

```
class DeleteMe(generic.DeleteView):
    template_name = 'deleteconfirmation.html'
    model = YourModel
    success_url = '/YourRedirectUrl/'
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^deleteurl/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', 
    views.DeleteMe.as_view(), name='deletemeview'),
```

deleteconfirmation.html

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <p>Are you sure you want to delete "{{ object }}"?</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm" />
</form>
```

Again, this is without the use of Ajax.

The views and template are taken directly from the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#deleteview)

Answer (score 0):

Using POST is our priority, but I thought that adding another form will be redundant.

Found solution in [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/)' email view.
Though it doesn't include confirmation step (as in docs, mentioned by @HoneyNutIchiros or [in more details](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-create-a-delete-view-with-Python-in-Django.php), or via [`onclick`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849117/html-how-to-do-a-confirmation-popup-to-a-submit-button-and-then-send-the-reque)), it can be useful.
They add name (`action_remove`) to button and check it in the `request.POST` dict:

```
# account/email.html
<button type="submit" name="action_primary" >{% trans 'Make Primary' %}</button>
<button type="submit" name="action_send" >{% trans 'Re-send Verification' %}</button>
<button type="submit" name="action_remove" >{% trans 'Remove' %}</button>
...
<button name="action_add" type="submit">{% trans "Add E-mail" %}</button>

# account/views.py
class EmailView(AjaxCapableProcessFormViewMixin, FormView):
    ...
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        if "action_add" in request.POST:
            res = super(EmailView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        elif "action_remove" in request.POST:
            res = self._action_remove(request)
        ...
        return res
```