# Django not receiving any request in backend after submit the form

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Hi Everyone I am trying to submit the form in Django. but I am not getting any response in Backend. when I clicked on submit. the form is not getting submitted.

The code

Models

```
class JobListing(models.Model):
    position = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    company_name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    about_company = models.TextField(blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    job_location = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    KeySkill = models.TextField()
    eligiblity = models.TextField(blank=True)
    resposibility = models.TextField(blank=True)
    min_experience = models.FloatField()
    max_experience = models.FloatField()
    last_date_to_apply = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    min_salary = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    max_salary = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    shift_time = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=shiftDetail)
    posted = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    number_of_position_opening = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    job_post_status = models.IntegerField(default=1, choices=job_post_status)

    def save(self, *arg, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.position)
        super(JobListing, self).save(*arg, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.position) + " -- " + str(self.company_name)
```

Form.py

```
class JobList(forms.ModelForm, forms.Form):
    job_location = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=CountryAndState.objects.filter(country__isnull=False).distinct())
    Key_Skill = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=skill.objects.all().values_list('name', flat=True).distinct().order_by('name'),
        widget=forms.SelectMultiple, required=False, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        model = JobListing
        fields = ['position', 'number_of_position_opening', 'company_name', 'about_company', 'description',
                  'eligiblity', 'resposibility', 'city',
                  'job_location', 'KeySkill', 'Key_Skill', 'min_experience', 'max_experience', 'min_salary',
                  'max_salary', 'shift_time', 'last_date_to_apply']

        exclude = ['slug', 'posted']
        widgets = {
            'KeySkill': forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':'text'}),
            'about_company': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 100, 'cols': 15}),
            'last_date_to_apply': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type':'date'})
        }

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(JobList, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields.keys():
            widget = self.fields[field].widget
            if 'cols' in widget.attrs and 'rows' in widget.attrs:
                widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control pl-15 bg-transparent summernote'})
            else:
                widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control pl-15 bg-transparent'})
            widget.attrs['placeholder'] = self.fields[field].label
            self.fields[field].required = False
            self.fields['company_name'].queryset = User.objects.filter(created_by=user, user_type=4)
```

View.py

```
class JobCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'Job/Recruiter/PostNewJob.html'
    template_name2 = 'Job/RecruiterAgency/PostNewJob.html'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        joblist = JobList(request.user.id)
        if request.user.user_type == 2:
            return render(request, self.template_name, {"form": joblist})
        elif request.user.user_type == 3:
            return render(request, self.template_name2, {"form": joblist})

    def post(self, request):
        job_detail = JobList(request.user.id, request.POST)
        field = job_detail.fields.pop('Key_Skill')
        if job_detail.is_valid():
            job_detail.save()
            return redirect('/job/manage_job')
        job_detail.fields['Key_Skill'] = field
        if request.user.user_type == 2:
            return render(request, self.template_name, {"form": job_detail})
        elif request.user.user_type == 3:
            return render(request, self.template_name2, {"form": job_detail})
```

template.html

```
{%extends 'index.html'%}
<body class="hold-transition light-skin sidebar-mini theme-primary">
    {%block body%}

    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <h1>Create New Job</h1>
        <div class="">
            <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="form">
          {%csrf_token%}
          <div>
            {{form.as_p}}
            {{form.errors}}
          </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Submit" form="form"> Submit </button>
      </form>
</div>
```

I have tried both Submit method with Input tags as well as Button. I tried debugging the code but am not receiving any requests in the backend. submit button is acting like it is disable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete object with form in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50547018/delete-object-with-form-in-django)

Comment: Hi @IvanStarostin, The above answer is not suitable for my question

Answer (score 0):

You added **action** as blank in form tag

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="form">
```

add appropriate url name in form tag

```
<form action="{% url 'post_url_name' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="form">
```

Comment: Hi @hafeezpp I tried this too but still not working

Comment: Can you see URL in the django teminal ?

Comment: No that's the problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).