# NodeJS Confirmation Prompt

Tags: node.js

I am writing a short JS script and will make a .exe out of it.
This script simply copies certain files and folders (embedded on the exe file - using `pkg` module).

Since this is on Node, is there any way I can add a confirmation message first before the actual script is called? Something like "*This will copy files to your this and that. Do you want to proceed?*" AFAIK, the confirmation prompts are only supported on browser mode.

I am aware of the `readline` module, but what I need is a more user-friendly UI such as a popup confirmation window.

Help! Thanks!

Comment: So you want a command line confirmation? Take a look at [the readline example in the node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_readline)

Comment: Hi ! A popup at frontend ?

Comment: Hi @Taxel . Thanks! I updated my post regarding ```readline```. Thanks!

Comment: @Philippe - yes! Even a very very simple one

Comment: Popup windows in commandline tools are rather unusual. Furthermore they may not even be supported in many environments. What happens, if the script is executed while connected via ssh?

Comment: Assuming the end user is on an html page, here is a minimalist approach : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16849178/4698373

Comment: Or [this specialized package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/confirm-dialog)