# Call JS function on click of a button in a Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap modal, where I have few buttons to capture feedback.

I want to call a JS function on click of one of the buttons.

However, on click of the button, the modal just closes without calling the JS Function.

But, if I do the same onclick event on any other element not in the modal, it works fine.

**js**

```
<script>
          
   function sayHello() {
        alert("Demo Alert")
   }
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div
class="modal fade"
id="exampleModal"
tabindex="-1"
role="dialog"
aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
aria-hidden="true"
>
<div
  class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered"
  role="document"
>
  <div class="appie-signup-area">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="appie-signup-box">
            <h3 class="title">How was the Session?</h3>
            <form action="#" id="mood-tracker">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="input-box">
                    <button type="submit" value="Good" onclick="sayHello()">
                      <i
                        class="fa fa-smile"
                       
                      ></i
                      >Good
                    </button>
                  </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You have to change button type as a "button" instead of "submit"

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use button type "submit". Use type "button" instead of like this:

```
<button type="button" value="Good" onclick="sayHello()"><i class="fa fa-smile"></i>Good </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

C must be capital

use onClick not onclick

```
<button type="button" onClick="sayHello()">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [window.confirm()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) instead of [window.alert()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert).

HTML

```
<button type="submit" value="Good" onclick="sayHello()">
```

JS

```
function sayHello() {
   return confirm('Demo Alert');
}
```

I found this answer on another Stack Overflow page : [HTML - How to do a Confirmation popup to a Submit button and then send the request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849117/html-how-to-do-a-confirmation-popup-to-a-submit-button-and-then-send-the-reque)