# django ask confirmation after rendering a message

Tags: django, render, confirmation

I have a form that needs a continue confirmation after the form is submitted.
The form has multiple actions (like "repair" and sell) that first calculates someting before asking the confirmation.
I was thinking about storing the request.POST temporary in a session while you ask the user the confirmation.

However i would like to put the confirmation in an alert-like pop-up, instead of rendering a whole new page.

Any suggestions about how i can render this message after the form submit?

with kind regards,
Hans

Answer (score 0):

this might help: [Django form: ask for confirmation before committing to db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728227/django-form-ask-for-confirmation-before-committing-to-db)

The answer (no points) is of the questionar himselve, with the title 'Solution'.